# Отображение двух знаков после запятой при округлении

Tags: java

Приветствую всех. Кто знает как сделать чтобы после округления числа типа double стояли два знака после него.

```
int i=3,j=7;
double var, result;
var = (double)(i*100)/j;
result = Math.rint(100.0 * var) / 100.0;
System.out.println(var);
System.out.println(result);
```

выдает  42.857142857142854

42.86

Но если округление проходит до целого числа, например при `i=1` `j=4` то результатом будет `25.0`. Но мне надо чтобы было `25.00`. Спасибо.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться [java.util.Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html), разделитель целой и десятичной частей зависит от [java.util.Locale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html):

```
System.out.println(String.format("%(.2f Default locale", var));
System.out.println(String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%(.2f English locale", var));
System.out.println(String.format(new Locale("ru"), "%(.2f Russian locale", var));
```

Выведет:

```
42.86 Default locale
42.86 English locale
42,86 Russian locale
```

Answer (score 6):

Чтобы отображать два знака после запятой при преобразовании числа в строку,  используйте класс [java.text.DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).

```
String pattern = "##0.00";
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat(pattern);
String format = decimalFormat.format(25.0000);
System.out.println(format);
```

выведет: `25.00`

Comment: Можно также посмотреть [printf](http://danilov-jee.blogspot.ru/2013/03/printf.html) в Java (может будет привычней).

Comment: спасибо за быстрый ответ. Да это работает но у меня выводит 25,00 вместо 25.00. Мне критична именно точкамежду цифрами.

Comment: можно так format = format.replace("," ,"."); Но по моему это не очень красиво.

Comment: спасибо то что нужно

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Locale locale = new Locale("en");
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        String pattern = "##0.00";
        DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat(pattern);
        String format = decimalFormat.format(25.0000);
        System.out.println(format);

    }
```

надо выставить стандартную локализацию как английскую, в ней как раз разделитель точка.

Comment: чем ответ отличается от соседнего ответа @Nofate?

Comment: Наличием установки Locale

Answer (score 0):

```
double var = 15.395974555;

System.out.printf("%.2f",(double)(Math.round( var*100))/100);
```

вывод : 15.40

```
double var = 15.995974555;
```

вывод : 16.00